# Avoiding messy validation code

Tags: php

I am currently making a simple login/register system for my website, and I'm not so happy about a part of my code.

I have a script that checks if any of the fields in the register-form is empty, and gives a proper response, say if you forgot to type a first name, it tells you "First name cannot be empty".

My problem is that my code currently looks like this:

```
if(field1 != ""){
  if(field2 != ""){
    if(field3 !=""){
      //register user
    }else{
      //field3 empty error
    }
  }else{
  //field2 empty error
  }
}else{
//field1 empty error
}
```

Is there a cleaner and more efficent way of doing this, that still lets me show exactly what field is left empty?

Comment: Google: `elseif()`

Comment: Use some sort of validation library for PHP or create your own for reuse.

Comment: This kind of logic is well suited to a front-end language so that the user can get more immediate feedback of any issues. You could then have much simpler logic in the back-end, i.e. "Register or don't register".

Comment: I would validate client side first `(JavaScript)` then pass to the server for data validation. Switch statements could help with the messy code issue

Comment: That doesnt change a thing for server side 'messy'  code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<?php

$errors = [];
if ($field1 === '') {
  $errors['field1'] = 'Empty error.'.
}
if ($field2 === '') {
  $errors['field2'] = 'Empty error.'.
}
if ($field3 === '') {
  $errors['field3'] = 'Empty error.'.
}

if (count($errors) === 0) {
  // Registration
} else {
  // Error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` loop with array of fields and validation messages. Just put your form fields in another array(`$form`)(or use variable variables).

```
$fields = [
'field1' => 'empty field1',
'field2' => 'empty field2',
'field3' => 'empty field3'
];
$errors = [];

foreach ($fields as $field => $message){
  if ($form[$field] !== ''){
    $errors[$field] => $message;
  }
}

if ($errors){
  //report errors
}
```

Bonus: you can add different validation rules to your `$fields` array. I will use [beberlei/assert](https://github.com/beberlei/assert) library, but you can pick anything you want.

```
use Assert\Assertion;
$fields = [
  'field1' => ['message' => 'empty field1', 'rule' => 'notEmpty'
];

$errors = [];

foreach ($fields as $field => $rules){
   try {
     call_user_func_array('Assertion::' . $rules['rule'], [$form[$field], $rules['message']]);
   } catch(AssertionFailedException $e) {
     $e->getValue(); // the value that caused the failure
   }
}
```

Comment: This solution is very specific to this answer. E.g.: Add a email=email-pattern check. Or a 8min length for password, but 3 for a username :)

Comment: No, but common sense can predict that this will happen :) Even if OP doesnt want it now, if this gets slightly more complex, this answer will wall him :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **elseif**, and reverse the logic to first test if everything is neat:

```
    if( $field1 =="" ){ $error = "no field1 value"; }
elseif( $field2 =="" ){ $error = "no field2 value"; }
elseif( $field3 =="" ){ $error = "no field3 value"; }
else{
    // your magic here, everything is clean.
}
```

Alternatively you can use an array and remember all errors in one go:

```
$errors = [];

if( $field1 =="" ){ $errors[] = "no field1 value"; }
if( $field2 =="" ){ $errors[] = "no field2 value"; }
if( $field3 =="" ){ $errors[] = "no field3 value"; }

// Again, first check if we have any problems:
if( count($errors)!==0 ){
    echo "something was incorrect:<br />".implode("<br />", $errors);
}
else{
    // your magic here, everything is clean.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about style like this:

```
$aErrors = array();

if(field1 == "") {
    $aErrors[] = 'error 1';
}
if(field2 == "") {
    $aErrors[] = 'error 2';
}
if(field3 == "") {
    $aErrors[] = 'error 3';
}

if(empty($aErrors)) register();
else print_errors();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to use validation functions on a separate `php` file and include them on whatever the page you want.

For what you're doing, the presence check, you can use a simple `foreach loop` to check all the necessary fields if they're empty.

**On your `register.php` page :**

```
$required_fields = array('first_name','last_name', 'phone', 'email', 'password');
validate_has_presense($required_fields);
```

**On `validation_functions.php` page**

```
function has_presense($value){
    return isset($value)&& $value !== "";
}

function validate_has_presense($required_fields){
    global $errors;

    foreach ($required_fields as $field){
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if(!has_presense($value)){
            $errors[$field] = "Please enter ".str_replace("_", " ", $field);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this way of presence validation is much more cleaner than writing `if` and `elseif` over and over again...

Comment: While this is a good way to do it, it's not entirely what I was looking for, as I want to be able to display a separate error message for each field, such as "Username can not be empty" and "Please enter an email". Thanks for your input, though!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'd want to check each of the fields by order, and return only one error, if it occurs.

```
function error($message) {
    exit('Error: ' . $message);
}

if ($field1 == "") { //You can also use if(empty(trim($field1)))
    error('Empty field 1');
}
if ($field2 == "") {
    error('Empty field 2');
}
if ($field3 == "") {
    error('Empty field 3');
}
... //Do your magic
```

Instead of `exit()` in the `error` function, you can use your own logic, depending on the code. Hope this helps